# I am developing a geolocation django application but getting error in postgis. please tell me what i am doing wrong

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, postgis-installation

Currently, I am trying to build an application with Django geolocation using PostGIS and PostgreSQL but getting following error. I have inserted all libraries required but whenever I try to migrate the models i get error **No such file or directory**

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "C:/Program 
Files/PostgreSQL/12/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

**My settings.py file looks something like this**

```
"""
Django settings for geodjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
   # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


  # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
  # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

  # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
  SECRET_KEY = ')l@*3+2b@s()dvuyhjzgb*5p(x^(qp(!-ci(doykaso*=7_z-%'

  # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
  DEBUG = True

  ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


 # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'geoapp',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'geodjango.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'geodjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

 DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PASSWORD':'1234',
    'PORT':'5433',
 }
 }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
 },
 ]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is my settings.py file here I also updated my database settings according to geolocation project requirement. I am using pgAdmin4 with postgresql12 version.

Comment: Engineering Projects, try to use prepared docker container with postgresql and postgis if you can't handle preparing postgresql on your own

Comment: Have you installed postgis at all as you are missing extension files

Comment: which extension files

Comment: Clearly postgis -> /extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory